# Powershell mandatory bool always true

Tags: powershell, parameters, casting

I have a script that includes the following settings which returns an incorrect result if I use the mandatory parameter screen. It feels like it is failing to do some kind of type verification or casting on my input. How can I resolve it?

```
param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [bool]$autoinstall )

if ( $autoinstall  ) 
{
    echo "Autoinstall true"
}
else
{
    echo "Autoinstall false"
}
```

This works perfectly if I call it with .\myscript.ps1 -autoinstall $false but the $autoinstall variable is always true regardless of what I pass if I use the mandatory password prompt and enter '$false'.

EDIT:

Using a switch doesn't work for me. I really need to have this be both scriptable and the mandatory parameter function for user shortcuts for on the fly use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue occurs because the input is interpreted as a string and you're seeing the results of PowerShell's coercion of string to bool e.g.:

```
59> [bool]'0'
True

60> [bool]'false'
True

61> [bool]'False'
True

62> [bool]'$false'
True
```

To get the "false" path to execute, just press enter when you're prompted for the parameter i.e.:

```
63> [bool]''
False
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use switch? Try this:

```
param ( [switch]$autoinstall )

if ( $autoinstall  ) 
{
    echo "Autoinstall true"
}
else
{
    echo "Autoinstall false"
}
```

Output:

```
[20:40:46] PS-ADMIN C:\Users\Graimer\Desktop> .\Untitled4.ps1
Autoinstall false
[20:42:36] PS-ADMIN C:\Users\Graimer\Desktop> .\Untitled4.ps1 -autoinstall
Autoinstall true
[20:42:38] PS-ADMIN C:\Users\Graimer\Desktop> .\Untitled4.ps1 -autoinstall:$true
Autoinstall true
[20:42:41] PS-ADMIN C:\Users\Graimer\Desktop> .\Untitled4.ps1 -autoinstall:$false
Autoinstall false
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I need to push out a single shortcut which uses a collection of mandatory parameters to control the behavior of the app. Had a note to that effect in the original version of my post.. I'll edit it back in.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit stupid today, because I can't understand the problem :) A switch is a mandatory boolean. Either you specify it or you don't, and in a script you can specify it's value. The switch is perfect in my eyes. See the updated output-section in my answer for proof-of-concept.

Comment: The script needs to be able to be called - regardless of other command line parameters which are already on the shortcut - and prompt via the mandatory parameter screen to have a value input. Try your script with a mandatory param for the switch and don't enter a value at the command line. You'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I know I am a little late to the game but, to accomplish what I needed, I had to take in the parameter as a string and check for the string '$true' and/or '$false'.  This works in my scenario anyway.